# Proposal: "Trivia" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a category of questions, which will never bother a learner of German, but is more about curiosities. Within two minutes I collected these examples:

- [Verben mit den meisten Vokalwechseln](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30566/1696)
- [Welches deutsche Wort hat die meisten Konsonanten in Folge?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2048/1696)
- [Welche vollständigen Teekesselchen gibt es?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/29190/1696)

A tag "trivia" is in my opinion appropriate, but I'm unsure, whether a new tag is justified for this somewhat exotic category.

Answer (score 3):

I created a tag [curiosities](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curiosities) with exactly this in mind, but I have no strong opinion on the name. (If you have, please add an answer, such that this can be voted upon.)

However, my criterion is less that such questions won’t bother learners but are about language records, singularities, and so on.

Comment: Curiosities is just as fine for me.

Comment: I think _curiosities_ is more appropriate, but _trivia_ is more likely to be entered without knowing about the exact tag name (as is _records_, which is already an alias). Maybe it should be featured in the short description.

Comment: We can always synonymise [trivia] to [curiosities]. Also, feel free to improve the tag wiki.